# Deleting a line from a text file on Windows Form Application using Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make a button which will remove a line from a text file using dictionary but when it deletes the line the rest of the lines appear to be the keys of the dictionary only with no values, any help?
Edit: Before deleting the line the file looks like : 
Believer,Rock,665498
Native,Rock,597264
After the deletion the file look like *if i delete the line of believer*:
Native,,
 :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pathsource = @"C:\Users\maher\Downloads\CDs.txt";
    string name = textBox1.Text;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathsource);
    Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>> MS = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
    while (reader.Peek() != -1)
    {
        string s;
        string[] fasl;
        s = reader.ReadLine();
        fasl = s.Split(',');
        MS.Add(fasl[0], kvp);
    }

    reader.Close();
    MS.Remove(name);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new S      treamWriter(pathsource, false))
    {
        foreach(var entry in MS)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", entry.Key, entry.Value.Key,entry.Value.Value);
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("CD Removed");
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox1.Focus();   
}
```

Comment: why are you using kvp when you are not using it?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need a Dictionary, can you show us an example of what the lines look like and what you want removed..? why not read all the lines into a List<string> and check if the name is in that line, and remove that line from the list..? then write back / save to a new or same file..?

Comment: Sunil I can’t understand your question..

Comment: @MethodMan Before removing the line the file looks like this : Believer,Rock,665879 *next line* Halet Hob,Romantic,655297.                After the remove the file look like: Halet Hob,,

Comment: looks like what @MaherFarghaly, update your question to show what it looks like in the code you posted..

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: There are no values in your output because you aren't adding any.  In your MS.Add(...) call, you're adding the key and the kvp, but your kvp is initialized outside of the loop to an empty KeyValuePair.

Comment: before putting it outside the loop it was inside it and the same results were found

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your output looks like

Native,,

is that you are writing the comma delineated key, kvp.key, and kvp.value to the line, but you are never actually setting the kvp.

```
while (reader.Peek() != -1)
{
    string s;
    string[] fasl;
    s = reader.ReadLine();
    fasl = s.Split(',');
    // Add these
    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fasl[1], fasl[2]);
    // So that the kvp is set
    MS.Add(fasl[0], kvp);
}
```

Comment: there is error showed under *kvp.Key* = “property or indexer ‘KeyValuePair<string,string>.Key’ cannot be assigned to — it is read only”

Comment: My bad - you'll need to set it in the constructor.  I'll update

Comment: Thankyou,very useful.